# can not init input[number] with a default value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how can I preset an input[Number] field with an integer value?

I created a plunk, where it does not work out: http://plnkr.co/edit/6WScrTkhB0ffkOsvPW2X

```
<form name="tokenDataForm" role="form" ng-show="editFlag" validate>
    <input type="{{ inputType }}" ng-model="tokenData"
           class="form-control"  />
</form>
```

Thanks a lot and kind regards
Cornelius

Comment: When you press edit, do you want it to have a default value? In that case add `value='10'` to the `<input>`. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iVrIT0SKAwlqWixrevJr?p=preview)

Comment: what is not working? you defined the fax as type=number and the button is disabled unless you type in a valid number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-value` :

```
<form name="tokenDataForm" role="form" ng-show="editFlag" validate>
    <input type="{{ inputType }}" ng-model="tokenData"
           class="form-control" ng-value="20" />
</form>
```